# How do I print the triangular series onto a file using PHP?

Tags: php

What i'm trying to do is create a file with the name `triangular_10.txt` where the number in the file name is the number the user entered. From there I want the text file to have the triangular series of numbers. So if the user enters 10, it'll display the first 10 numbers of the triangular series. So far the file name change is working.

The algorithm is here that I used for PHP:
http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_a_triangle_number

**eg.** user enters 10. Result in `txt` file is first 10 numbers in the `triangular series = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]`

This is what I have so far but I'm not having any luck! At the moment its only writing the number I entered on to the `txt` file and nothing else!

```php
        $number = $_POST['number-entered'];
        foreach(range(1, 1000) as $i) {
            $triangle_numbers[] = $i * ($i + 1) / 2;
        }

        //make a file
        $contents = fopen('gs://a1-task22020.appspot.com/triangular_'.$number. ".txt", "w");
        fwrite($contents, $number);

        //open the file
        $contents = fopen('gs://a1-task22020.appspot.com/'.$contents, 'w');

        // re-open the document if you put something in it
        fwrite($contents, $number);

        fclose($contents);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what you actually write to the file?  You add the numbers to `$triangle_numbers`.

Comment: Content of $triangle_numbers array is not used anywhere. Try putting ```fwrite($contents, implode(', ', $triangle_numbers));``` in your code and check the file.

Comment: A breakpoint when debugging would allow you to examine the contents of your variables, and then the error would be obvious

Comment: @matek997 I tried that but its printing out literally the whole 1000 numbers instead of the amount I entered

Comment: @JoshGomez why do you go ```range(1,1000)``` in loop? Try doing ```$number = intval($_POST['number-entered']); for($i=1;$i<=$number;$i++){ /*loop code*/}```. This makes your code work for any number, not only 1-1000 and will create only needed amount of elements.
Alternatively, you can do  ```$number = intval($_POST['number-entered']);``` and write ```range(1,$number);``` if you don't want to change the loop.

Comment: @JoshGomez take one of the solutions above and don't remove ```fwrite($contents, implode(', ', $triangle_numbers));```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I got confirmed that saving to file itself is not an issue, I am posting 3 solutions

```
$number = intval($_POST['number-entered']); // convert target number to string;
$triangle_numbers = [];

// SOLUTION 0 (no change to your loop, but you should use something else, range(1,1000) is very bad there)
foreach (range(1, 1000) as $i) {
    $triangle_numbers[] = $i * ($i + 1) / 2;
}
$triangle_numbers = array_slice($triangle_numbers,0,$number);

// SOLUTION 1:
foreach ( range(1, $number) as $i ) { //we don't need to go all the way to 1000 if user only wants 5, and if they want 2000 we are covered
$triangle_numbers[] = $i * ( $i + 1 ) / 2;
}


// SOLUTION 2 
for ($i = 1; $i<=$number; $i++) { //it's as above, i just changed the loop
    $triangle_numbers[] = $i * ($i + 1) / 2;
}

// rest is pretty much the same
//edit, i removed weird reopen part. it made you write to the same line over and over
        $contents = fopen('here.txt', "w");
    fwrite($contents, $number . "\n");
    fwrite($contents, implode(', ', $triangle_numbers)); // read https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php
    fwrite($contents, "\n$number\n");
    fclose($contents);
```